# Javascript "Equal Sequence" meaning

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sometimes in the internet I see a syntax that is strange to me. Something like:

```
console.log = console.error = console.info = console.debug = console.warn = console.trace = function() {}
```

How does this "equal" sequence work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand.

Consider:

```
a = b = c = d = 5;
```

The expression is resolved right to left so:

`d = 5` and `c = d` (which is 5), `b = c` (5) and so on.

In your example those console methods are all being (re)defined as an empty function.

---

See: [MDN: Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) for more info.

Answer (score 5):

With assignments, the operations are resolved from right to left.  So the right most value will be populated into all the preceding variables.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe can be easily explained by analogy using a simpler example:

```js
// Normal variable assignment
var a, b;
a = 15;
b = 15;
console.log("a: "+a+" , b: "+b);
// Assing the same value to two variables
var c, d;
c = d = 15;
console.log("c: "+c+" , d: "+d);
// Assign the same value to two variables and make it a function
var e, f;
e = f = function(){ console.log("Hi!"); };
// Call both of the variables' functions
e(); f();
```

Starting from variables `a` and `b`, you then go to `c` and `d` that are given the same value. The takeaway here is that you can assign the same value to two variables and the expression will be evaluated from right to left, so in effect it's like assigning the two variables' values separately. However, this does not mean that chaning one will change the other as well.
Finally, see what happens with `e` and `f`. These are assigned a function instead of a value, so you can then call them as if they were functions.

**Short version**: Expression gets resolved from right to left. The assignment is by value, not by reference, meaning that changing one of the variables' value will not affect the others. Finally, if you assign a function to your variables, you can then use their names to call the function that is their value.